# Represent order of permutation using an integer?

Tags: c, algorithm

Assume there's `N` (N=10) letters A, B, ..., J. String `S` is an instance of the permutation.

I want to store the order of permutation by a 32-bit integer `p`, and to convert between the String `S` and the order `p`, and to validate the integer value, I have written something like this:

```
int S2P(char *s) {
    unsigned int p = 0;
    char c;
    while (c = *s++) {
        c -= 'A'; 
        p *= 10; 
        p += c; 
    }
    return p; 
}

char *P2S(unsigned int p, char *buf) {
    char *s = buf + 10; 
    char used[20], *t;
    int i, j, c; 
    strcpy(used, "ABCDEFGHIJ"); 
    *s-- = '\0';
    for (i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        *s-- = c = 'A' + (p % 10); 
        p /= 10; 
        t = strchr(used, c);
        if (t)
            *t = '-'; 
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        if (used[i] != '-')
            *s = used[i];
    return buf; 
}

int PCheck(int p) {
    char tmp[20];
    int q = S2P(P2S(p, tmp)); 
    return p == q;
}
```

It's working not so efficient. That means,

1. It's not possible to add one more letter. (max(N) = 10)
2. In `P2S`, an extra lookup table is used, to find out the 10th letter.
3. `PCheck(int)` is too slow.

How to make it better? A straight piece of code is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "working but buggy"? If it's buggy then I wouldn't say it's working. I think you should describe your algorithm rather than post code, that would make it easier for more people to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any better algorithm?

Check out [Knuth's TAOCP](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/taocp.html) Volume 4 Fascicle 2, Generating All Tuples and Permutations (I think it will be out in physical book form very soon, though). He addresses this problem there.

Comment: Is that fascicle up for download at that site? Because I can't find it.

Comment: @IVlad: Try the pre-fascicle 2B on this page: http://cs.utsa.edu/~wagner/knuth/, or you can buy a copy of the full fascicle here: http://www.amazon.com/Art-Computer-Programming-Fascicle-Permutations/dp/0201853930 (or probably get a copy from your local library).

Answer (score 2):

I think you are interested in the [factoradic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factoradic). This allows you to find what the `n`th lexicographic permutation of `0 1 ... n - 1` is and what position a given permutation of the same set has in the lexicographic ordering of all permutations, and it's also efficient.