# Numbering permutations

Tags: lexicographic-ordering

Given an alphabet `A = {a,b,c,d,...}` of length n, I would like to get all permutations of length r (r < n).

Now I would like to number these permutations, and there should be a reverse mapping.

For example:

```
A = {a,b,c}, r = 2

ab -> 0
ba -> 1
ac -> 2
ca -> 3
...
```

How can I achieve this? I have found it for problems which are order-invariant. But I cant apply it to this situation with the order.

Is there some library doing it in python?

Comment: Once you've generated the r-permutations in order, you can flop the array to create a dictionary. The keys are the permutations and the values are the old array indices. (Your question implies that you are doing this in O(r!) space.)

Comment: If you genuinely need the closed form, see for instance the answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4595928/represent-order-of-permutation-using-an-integer

Comment: @nuemlouno: Can you confirm that with permutations each element of the alphabet only appears once? And that the translation for one element to a number (n-th element of the alphabet) <-> (n) is trivial in your case?

Comment: You divide the number in a loop by n...n-r+1 and get the element indices (0..n-1) as remainder. The used up elements of the alphabet don't count. E.g. 5 in your example gives 5%3=2; 5/3=1; 1%2=1;1/2=0. The positions from the remainders are 2 and 1, which is cb. Other example: 4%3=1; 4/3=1; 1%2=1; 1/2=0. The positions are 1 and 1, which is bc (for the second letter of the permutation only {a, c} remain, after b is used, so index 1 now is c).

Answer (score 0):

Presumably `aa` is an invalid selection. Since you are dealing from a distinct alphabet, each deal produces a non-intersecting set of permutations. Your list is counted by `r! * choose(n,r)` which is `n!/(n-r)!` or `n_r` or "k-permutations of n elements." The canonical way to number these is lexicographically.

If I were attempting to generate these using a generic library, I would find a way to deal or choose the unrepeated `r` elements, then produce all permutations on that set of size `r`. As far as numbering goes, if you can store the permutations lexicographically in an array you can binsearch to find the index. It is possible to reverse the mapping analytically, but realistically, whatever you're doing here is going to have to have small `r`.

A quick search shows Python's `itertools` give you two functions you need: `combinations` and `permutations`.

Comment: The analytic solution is not soo unrealistic!

Comment: You misread. The point is that his `r` is small, so there's no sense going further.

Comment: where did i say my r is small

Comment: Two cases: your `r` is small and you brazenly don't know it yet, or, improbably, your `r` is large and you are trolling us with malformed questioning. Either way my participation here ends.

Comment: I do not see, where the OP should have lead us astray. Perhaps there was a misunderstanding, but trolling?

Answer (score 0):

We know that there are n permutations of length one (where n is the length of the alphabet).  Permutations of length r are all of the permutations of length r-1 appended with each of the n elements in the alphabet. There are n^r of these.

Assigning ids permutations is straight-forward, since generating permutations and counting are really the same thing.

Here, in JS, we compute permutations or length r with any array of characters. To illustrate the idea about counting, see the output when the alphabet is the set of digits '0'='9'...

```js
function permute(r, alphabet) {
  if (r === 1) return alphabet
  let result = []
  let r1 = permute(r-1, alphabet)
  for (let p of r1) {
    for (let a of alphabet) {
      result.push(p+a)
    }
  }
  return result
}

const permutations = permute(3, ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']);
const withIds = permutations.map((value, id) => ({id, value}));
console.log(withIds);
```

Same thing in python...

```
def permute(r, alphabet):
    if r == 1: return alphabet
    result = []
    r1 = permute(r-1, alphabet)
    for p in r1:
        for a in alphabet:
            result.append(p+a)
    return result
```

Comment: but where is here the map to the id I am asking for

Comment: @nuemlouno - Since the results are unique strings, they can be used as their own ids, and so can their positions in an enumeration. I edited to clarify / demonstrate/

Comment: I see, so for a given n  I need this list to get the corresponding permutation?

Comment: @nuemlouno, yes. If we assign sequential ints (0,1,2,...), we can use N as an array index into the array of enumerated permutations.  Or we can use int ids keys in an an object where permutations are the values.  Finally (as I wasn't clear enough in explaining in the answer), the ids and the permutations can be understood as really the same thing. All the x-long permutations of y things, is really just like counting for 0 to y^x - 1 in a base x numbering system.

Comment: As an example in familiar terms: all of the 3-long permutations of the 10 Arabic numerals is really just like counting from 0-999 in a base 10 numbering system: (000, 001, 002, ... 999).  That's just as true for base 3, where the "numerals" are "A", "B", "C"